# Подлежащее "каждый"

Tags: пунктуация, члены-предложения

> Со всех сторон прибывали любопытные люди, и каждому хотелось взглянуть
> на маленького героя своими глазами.

Является ли "каждому" подлежащим? К сказуемому "хотелось взглянуть" вопрос есть, а на вопросы им. падежа не отвечает, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, *каждому* не является подлежащим. Эта фраза представляет собой односоставное предложение без подлежащего.

Конкретно, здесь имеет место безличное предложение, так как сказуемое *хотелось взглянуть* не предполагает наличия субъекта: глагол *хотелось* обозначает процесс, который никак не зависит от активных действий того, с кем он происходит.

*хотелось кому-то*

НО

*кто-то* не может *хотелось*

Что касается вопроса к сказуемому, то вы перепутали направление зависимости — это от сказуемого можно задать вопрос:

*хотелось взглянуть кому?* — *каждому*.

Здесь *каждому* — это классическое дополнение.

Comment: В соответствии с современными взглядами на грамматику безличных предложений субъект состояния присутствует в предложении, но он не может быть выражен И.п. и поэтому не является грамматическим подлежащим.

Comment: @Sharon Причем тут состояние? Состояние это "мне хорошо", а не "мне хотелось".

Comment: И еще насчет субъекта действия у безличных предложений: "Мне снилось." Вы же не будете говорить, что здесь субъект - это Я. А в "мне снился сон" субъект уже - сон?

Comment: @JKlen Современная лингвистика – это ее структурно-семантический вариант. Следует  различать семантический субъект и грамматический субъект, а  не смешивать эти понятия так, что невозможно разобраться, о чем вы в данный момент говорите – о семантике или о грамматике, вот что представляется мне некорректным. В струтурно-семантическом  анализе  И.п. – это классическая форма для выражения семантического субъекта,  но отнюдь не единственная форма. Новое семантическое направление является ведущим, оно было обозначено еще в 60-годах XX столетия.

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере слово «хотелось» является категорией состояние и, по общему согласованию, слово, обозначающее автора данного состояния(каждому), не считается подлежащим.

Answer (score 0):

*Со всех сторон прибывали любопытные люди, и **каждому хотелось взглянуть** на маленького героя своими глазами.*

Вторая часть – это **односоставное безличное предложение**, оно описывает   психическое состояния человека.

**Грамматического подлежащего** нет, сказуемое «хотелось взглянуть»  – это  составное глагольное сказуемое,  модальная связка  «хотелось» выражена  безлично-возвратным  вариантом  личного глагола  «хотеть».

Хотелось (кому?) – каждому (дополнение в форме Д.п.).

Безличные  предложения иногда считают **бессубъектными,** но это неточно.  Субъект как носитель признака или состояния там есть (в данном примере – слово ***каждый***),  причем он выражен грамматически, **обычно Р.п. иди Д. п.** существительного (или слова в значении существительного).

Особенность безличных предложений не в том, что там нет субъекта, а в том, что **он не может быть выражен И.п.**, как обычное подлежащее.